# How does URLSessionTask run

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, swift3

Say I have created an instance of `URLSessionTask`:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in 
   print (\(Thread.current))
}
// I start the task by
task.resume()
```

I want to understand whether the `URLSessionTask` instance is running on **main** thread by default or in **background** thread. So, I print the `Thread.current` .

When I run my code, it print out:

```
<NSThread: 0x170273980>{number = 4, name = (null)}
```

**My questions are:**

1. which thread the `URLSessionTask` is running by default? Main thread or background thread?
2. Why current thread shows null in thread `name`? Does it mean it is running in background thread by default? (I see name="main" for `print` on main thread)
3. In general, is it necessary to run `URLSessionTask` with GCD in order to force it run in background thread or not? I am asking this because I saw some tutorials doesn't use GCD to run `URLSessionTask`, they only use GCD to run completion handler in main thread.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Short answer: The key observation is that the `URLSessionTask` always runs asynchronously with respect to the thread that you started it. And unless you explicitly specify otherwise, the completion handlers and/or delegate methods will run on a background thread. So, you don't have to use GCD when initiating the request, but in the completion handler we will use GCD to dispatch anything that updates the UI or model to the main queue.

---

You asked:

> 1. Which thread the `URLSessionTask` is running by default? Main thread or background thread?

There are really two questions there: Which thread(s) `URLSession` uses internally for its own purposes and which thread the completion handler and/or delegate methods will be run.

On the former question, this is an internal implementation detail that is not documented anywhere, but it appears to create its own (background) thread with a separate run loop to process requests. But these implementation details generally don't really matter: We're assured is that the request runs asynchronously (does not block the current thread).

The latter question, on which thread the completion handlers and delegate methods are called, is generally far more important. Unless we specify otherwise, `URLSession` runs completion handlers and delegate methods on serial operation queue that `URLSession` created for us. That means that these run on a background thread.

The only exception to this rule is if you specified `OperationQueue.main` as the `queue` parameter when instantiating a `URLSession`, in which case it would obviously use the main thread for the completion handlers and delegate methods. But even in this case, the request runs asynchronously and `URLSession` will not block the main thread.

> 2. Why current thread shows null in thread name? Does it mean it is running in background thread by default? (I see name="main" for print on main thread)

It's running on a serial operation queue. The threads used by operation queues threads don't generally have names. But you can look at `OperationQueue.current?.name` to confirm which operation queue is being used.

> 3. In general, is it necessary to run `URLSessionTask` with GCD in order to force it run in background thread or not? I am asking this because I saw some tutorials doesn't use GCD to run `URLSessionTask`, they only use GCD to run completion handler in main thread.

The flow suggested by those tutorials is correct. You do not have to use GCD when initiating the request. It always runs asynchronously with respect to the queue from which you started it. The only thing you need to do is to dispatch relevant code within the completion handler or delegate method to the appropriate queue.

Specifically, since we generally let `URLSession` run completion handlers on its own serial queue, we therefore have to dispatch UI updates back to the main queue. Sometimes overlooked, we also generally dispatch model updates back to the main queue, too (or use some other synchronization mechanism).

Comment: Thanks, your answer mentions a "serial operation queue", etc. It is a informative answer, but I still don't get my expected answer, I create my URLSessionTask by `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(...)`, I would like to know which thread this task is running by default, main thread or background thread? Your answer always mention the queue, I am interested in the thread.

Comment: It runs on background thread. FYI, background queues use background threads. Main queue uses main thread. When the docs say that it "creates a serial operation queue", that means (a) it's a background queue; and (b) things added/dispatched to that queue will run on background threads. With the advent of GCD, dispatch queues, and operation queues (that do the thread housekeeping for us) we rarely interact directly with threads anymore.

Comment: Thanks, the above comment makes your answer very clear to me now.

Comment: Reading "but it appears to create its own (background) thread with a **separate run loop** to process requests." and then also reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10522969/5175709) "GCD dispatch threads **don't have run loops**". Are you saying something the opposite, or you're just talking about something else? Can you explain?

Comment: Background threads don't have their own runloops, but you can just add one. E.g. [AFNetworking 2.x did it](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/2.x/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m#L157). It was tried and true technique for `NSURLConnection` or `NSTimer` on background threads, but we don't do this ourselves much anymore, as newer APIs eliminate the need to do so. But it appears that `URLSession` does, e.g., [here is simple request](http://i.imgur.com/b3DYLTJ.png), running completion handlers on the main queue, and you can see it has a run loop on background thread.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. I've seen that thread trace in the left panel right a million times but never was never able to make sense of it.... Q) So would it be correct to say anything that gives us a future callback must have a runloop e.g. things like completionHandlers (but since we're using AlamoFire/URLSession we don't need one)/delegates need a runloop, user events (which already have main run loop), timers (if not on main thread) need a runloop?

Comment: No, it is not correct to jump to that conclusion. Lots (if not most) things that have callbacks do not employ runloops.